# Zabbix: Unable to determine "dbversion"

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, zabbix

I need your assistance, experience with zabbix and knowledge:
I configured everything like the [Avantistech](https://aventistech.com/kb/install-zabbix-5-lts-on-debian-10/) website says. Everything works fine until I try to continue setting up the zabbix server in the web UI. It says `"Unable to determine current Zabbix database version: the table "dbversion" was not found."`

Can you help me with that? That would be great!

I've attached a screenshot of the error message.

[image: Zabbix error message]

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was problem that:

`sudo zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql -u userzabbix -p zabbixdb`

did not worked. It was wrong path to script.

I was missing tables in database.
You can check this by going to mysql.

```
sudo mysql
mysql> use name_of_database_for_zabix;
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
```

This need show you list of tables in zabbix database. If they do not exist, upper command did not created it.

Exit from MySQL:

```
mysql>\q
```

run command again, with proper path (https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=6.2&os_distribution=ubuntu&os_version=22.04&components=server_frontend_agent&db=mysql&ws=nginx):

```
sudo zcat /usr/share/zabbix-sql-scripts/mysql/server.sql.gz | mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -u zabbix_user -p zabbix_db
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the database exists and the password is correct, otherwise you should get different error messages.

Probably something went wrong on "Import initial schema and data":

```
$ sudo zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql -u userzabbix -p zabbixdb
Enter password:
```

You should retry the command and watch out for issues or error messages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the wrong schema I had set, which was **public** on Postgres.